# JQuery- mouseenter and mouseleave on a div or img is "unstable"

Tags: jquery, mouseleave

I need a close/delete button-like div on a picture when mouse enters (hovers) on the picture. So, I create a small div which has a times character and positioning dynamically on the top left corner of the picture. When mouse moves inside the img area, this small div vibrates and when I want to hover this button-like div to click for an action, it does not behave as expected. It is somehow unstable.

```
var timesDiv;
timesDiv = $('<div title="Delete Picture">&times;</div>');
timesDiv.css({
    'position': 'absolute',
    'cursor': 'pointer',
    'width': '25px',
    'height': '25px',
    'line-height': '25px',
    'font-size': '22px',
    'font-weight': 'bolder',
    'background-color': 'red',
    'color': 'white',
    'text-align': 'center'
});
$('.editable-picture').on('mouseenter', function() {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    timesDiv.css({
        'top': offset.top + 'px',
        'left': offset.left + 'px',
        'display': 'block'
    });
    $('body').append(timesDiv);
});
$('.editable-picture').on('mouseleave', function() {
    timesDiv.css('display', 'none');
});
```

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/724L9/

I also tried hover:

```
$('.editable-picture').hover(function() {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    timesDiv.css({
        'top': offset.top + 'px',
        'left': offset.left + 'px',
        'display': 'block'
    });
    $('body').append(timesDiv);
}, function() {
    timesDiv.css('display', 'none');
});
```

[@Reinder Wit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23828607/3388317) Actually, I'm using "editable-picture" class as in:

```
<img class="editable-picture">
```

I need a dynamic solution, therefore I'm using javascript.

**Update:**

http://jsfiddle.net/jUuDS/

Comment: What do you mean by 'dynamic solution'? Please update your fiddle with more sample code...

Comment: @ReinderWit he wants to actually be able to remove the picture with that `x`

Comment: I cannot change the HTML of the image and cannot wrap it with a div or others. It has a class "editable-picture" and that's it. It can be anywhere in the page. I want a solution done from the JavaScript side. I mean by "dynamic", it should be independent of the html side, template or so on. Sorry for the wrong usages in English language...

Comment: I've update my answer. You can manipulate the DOM in any way you want, attaching all sorts of events to newly created tags.

Comment: @ReinderWit This looks awesome. In my case, img's have editable-picture class. http://jsfiddle.net/jUuDS/

I think I have to wrap the images as in your case, with JQuery.

Comment: I changed yours a little:
http://jsfiddle.net/8bcsd/

Comment: Do you mean you only have an image with that class or is the image still inside another div? Please show some more HTML markup, so I can adjust my fiddle accordingly. You maybe need to use jQuery wrap() instead of append()

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8bcsd/ Yes. Thank you. This is what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the button is flickering is because when you enter the div with the mouse, the new button is on top and outside of your `<div>`, generating a mouseleave event.

It's just as easy using pseudo class 'hover' on the parent div and some CSS.

Put the button inside the existing div using some jQuery code:

```
$('div.editable-picture').each(function() {
    $(this).append('<div class="delete">&times;</div>');
});
```

and set the `display` to **none** using CSS.
When hovering over the parent div, set the `display` to **block**:

```
.editable-picture:hover .delete {display:block}
```

Deleting the actual image from the DOM could be done like this:

```
$('.editable-picture div.delete').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('img').fadeOut('fast', function() {
         $(this).parent().remove();   
    });
});
```

Check out this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/724L9/9/)

**UPDATE:**

If you only have an `<img>` tag to work with, you have to change append() into wrap(), like so:

```
$('img.editable-picture').each(function () {
    $(this).wrap('<div class="editable-picture"></div>');
});
```

Demonstrated in [**this DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ReinderWit/724L9/11/)

Comment: So I conclude that my problem is, appending the div to the body. Instead, I need a wrap. Then, I should append to that wrap.

Comment: Check my update, which has only an image which is then wrapped inside another div. Ultimately, you'll end up with the same functionality as demonstrated in my first fiddle